# Page loaded over HTTPS but requrested insecure plugin resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, wordpress

I'm experiencing a problem with my website when I try to play embedded youtube video. Here's the error that I get on Chrome:

> Mixed Content: The page at X was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an
>   insecure plugin resource 'X'. This request has been blocked; the
>   content must be served over HTTPS.

For the videos I'm using a plugin called DisplayBuddy. If anyone had a problem like this and found a solution, please let me kno how can I fix this issue and enable the embedded videos to be played. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I seriousely dont know why somebody votes this question down, sounds like a real problem and not like a dumb question to me

Comment: @TomDoodler I didn't downvote but it's likely because there's no way of ascertaining the problem without seeing a live site... HTTPS mixed content warnings are thrown by assets resolving over HTTP, it all depends on the linked files, no way to suggest anything without seeing the site.

Comment: Ok, didnt know that, but i guess he doesnt know it either ^^

Comment: Sorry, forgot to send the ULR. Here's the website where the error occurs: https://www.wickededgeusa.com/videos/

Comment: If it only happens when you add that plugin, either your reference to the file is http or something is requesting an http resource in the plugin. If it is the plugin, you need to talk with the developer of it.

Comment: or load your page on http instead of https

Comment: I have used this plugin for my own site: [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/)